# sockets in c tcp

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

im tryin to send a 2d array in simple socket program..but this only sends the first row and never anything beyond that/....what is the problem here... ?

server part ...

```
struct sockaddr_in clienta,servera;
int s ;
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
servera.sin_family = AF_INET;
servera.sin_port = htons(3386);
servera.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
bind(s,(struct sockaddr *)&servera,sizeof(servera));
listen(s,1);
int news;
int len = sizeof(clienta);
printf("waiting for connection");
news = accept(s,(struct sockaddr *)&clienta , &len);
printf("\n received connection");
int c[3][3];
recv(news, &c,sizeof(c),0);
int d = sizeof(c);
int i=0,j=0;
for(;i<=2;i++)
    for(;j<=2;j++)
        printf("\n %i,%i,%i",i,j,c[i][j]);
printf("\n %i",c[1][0]);
```

here is the client program

```
    struct sockaddr_in servera;
int s ;
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
servera.sin_family = AF_INET;
servera.sin_port = htons(3386);
servera.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
connect(s,(struct sockaddr *)&servera, sizeof(servera));
int b[3][3];
int i=0,j=0;
for(;i<3;i++)
    for(;j<3;j++)
        b[i][j]=4;

printf("connected");
send(s,&b,sizeof(b),0);
int l = sizeof(b);
```

Comment: It helps to begin sentences with Capital Letters.  It helps to end them with One punctuation mark: '.' or '?'.  Please **update** your question to look good in English so that other people can easily read, understand and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know what these:

```
for(;i<=2;i++)
    for(;j<=2;j++)
        printf("\n %i,%i,%i",i,j,c[i][j]);
```

and

```
for(;i<=2;i++)
    for(;j<=2;j++)
       printf("\n %i,%i,%i",i,j,c[i][j]);
```

do? `j` is initialized just once (:

So, once `j` gets `3` on `i = 0`, when `i = 1` and `i = 2` `j` is still `3` and the second `for` is not executed, that's why you send only the first row.